# How to make desktop-notification in Google Chrome not topmost

Tags: google-chrome, desktop, notifications

I like Google Chrome's desktop notifications but don't want them to be in front of other windows than Chrome's mainwindow itself. I'm on a Windows-machine.

Is that possible?

Comment: Then you don't want desktop notifications...

Comment: I want the notifications, but only in front of Chrome but not other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think that's possible. Eve the various add-ons such as Google Mail Checker Plus display notifications on top of other windows.